# Working with ImageList Images

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Somewhat new to VS2010 and c#.
I've inherited a program, and among other things I'm trying to figure out how all these imagelists are set up.
Basically, right now I am trying to modify some existing imagelists to add more images, and then create a whole new imagelist as well.
I can't figure out how this works, though. All I can find in the code is stuff like

```
private ImageList fastenersImageList;
private ImageList controlsImageList;
```

and then some references back to them such as

```
this.ItemPictureBox.BackgroundImage = fastenersImageList.Images[3];
```

with different numbers in the brackets. I don't even know where to begin looking for the images! Any help?

Comment: I'd have a read of the ImageList documentation, there's some examples in there too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.aspx

Comment: the bracket number is the index of the image that is being retrieved.  When you debug, you should be able to view the ImageList variables and get an idea of what they have

Comment: I'd also look for where images are added to the lists. i.e. `fastenersImageList.Add();`

Comment: That's the thing, there is no ImageList.Add(); for anything. I have no idea how the images are being added to the lists.

Comment: Check the Forms Designer. There is probably an `ImageList` added there, and you edit it through the Properties window.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that already too, and the only thing there is a default error image and a default image, which is blank. It is a template that pulls different images depending on variables, etc.

Comment: I added this to my answer, but did you try Find All References?

Comment: In particular, look not only for `Add` calls but anywhere that the image lists might be getting passed to a function that could be calling `Add`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to right-click on the `ImageList` variables in the code window and click **Find All References** from the context menu. Even if it's added in the Designer view, it should show up when you do that. *Something* has to be adding the images to the lists. But keep in mind that if you pass an `ImageList` to a function or it is passed into the class where you are using it, then the `Add` calls may not show up when you do a **Find All References** - the references list should still show you where your `ImageList` is being assigned or where you are passing it to. You may have to follow a trail of breadcrumbs to get to what you're looking for.

If `ImageList` images were added by the Designer, you can look at them in the Designer itself. In the view that shows the Form you are designing, there will be a bar at the bottom with things like timers and image lists.

[image: Forms Designer]

If you click on the `ImageList` in the Designer view, the Properties window will have an Images field under the Appearance heading. If you click on the **...** button beside that it will show you the images that have been added through the Designer.

[image]

(These screenshots are from VS2013 Preview but it should be the same for 2010).

**Edit:** I moved the **Find All References** bit to the top because it's really the first thing you should try, but in case the image list was edited in the Designer, somebody looking at this question later may still find the screenshots useful, so I am leaving them there.

Comment: Yes! Thank you, there they are. It was actually in the parent form of the form I was looking at.

Comment: Just to clarify, you found it with Find All References, right?

Comment: No, I found it using the first steps. Part of the problem was I was looking in the wrong spot. Find All References didn't pan out, I just got a bunch of `controlsImageList.Images.SetKeyName(0,"");` etc

Comment: OK, just trying to make my answer useful to somebody looking at this in the future. I will edit.